# Image in UIButton doesn't scale when using Autolayout.

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout

I have a UIButton that I'd like to be as wide as the view and then have the height adjust in a fixed aspect ratio. I've set my constraints for the button to be as wide as the view. And the height to be in a 2:1 aspect ratio like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj1Bh.jpg)

But when I move it on to iPhone 6 or 6 Plus screen the image itself doesn't scale while the button does. I've added a green background color for empahsis. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrduZ.jpg)

The mode is set to Aspect Fill. And for the record I've tried multiple modes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When a constraint is orange in the Interface Builder this means there is something missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the image as the background image for the button instead of the image property.

Comment: That did it and I feel dumb. Thanks! Maybe someone can explain why that's the case.